# Firefox addons-sdk stop tab loading function

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Please write a function that stop load tab. To refresh a simple reload (); complaint is on the page sdk stopping function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to do a conditional statement. Is tab is loaded?

Comment: @Noitidart: you can delete your own comments (I'll do mine above now - good idea). A display of support is sometimes nice, but it's best to keep it brief and neutral, so there is little risk of it getting out of hand.

Comment: +1 and ill delete now. thx man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to stop the most recently used tab from loading its page. (note: the page has to be loading something)

```
const { getMostRecentBrowserWindow } = require('sdk/window/utils');
getMostRecentBrowserWindow().gBrowser.selectedBrowser.stop();
```

This one here reloads: `getMostRecentBrowserWindow().gBrowser.selectedBrowser.reload();`